# Laravel Test assertSessionDoesntHaveErrors() not picking up errors?

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

I want to assert two things in a Laravel test:

1. That an object was successfully changed (eg. `assertSee('New value')`)
2. That there were no errors in the session (eg. `assertSessionDoesntHaveErrors()`)

However to test the first, I need to use `followingRedirects()` in my `patch()` request, and to check the second I can't use `followingRedirects()` (otherwise the session errors are erased).

I could place a `data-errors="true"` element in my HTML body if there are any errors present, but I wondered if there's a more elegant solution? I feel there must be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my solution. It appears to work as expected:

```
$response = $this->patch('/endpoint', $object);

$response
  ->assertStatus(302)
  ->assertSessionDoesntHaveErrors();

$this->followRedirects($response)
  ->assertSee('New value')
  ->assertOk();
```